# Spring data jpa:QuerySyntaxException: department is not mapped

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am using spring data jpa.I write a query using @query annotation and trying to fetch all columns in a table but while implementing i am getting error that department table is not mapped.

**DepartmentsRepository**

```
 @Repository
    public interface DepartmentsRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> 
    {
        @Query(value = "select d from department d")
        public List<Department> findColumns();
    }
```

**Department class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="department")
public class Department 
{
@Id
@Column(name="ndept_id")
public int ndept_id;

@Column(name="sdept_name")
public String sdept_name;

@Column(name="ninst_id")
public int ninst_id;

@Column(name="bis_locked")
public boolean bis_locked;

@Column(name="sclient_dept_id")
public String sclient_dept_id;

@Column(name="nsurvey_method_id")
public  int nsurvey_method_id;

@Column(name="bis_jointuse")
public boolean bis_jointuse;

@Column(name="ntemp_dept_id")
public int ntemp_dept_id;

@Column(name="balternate_jointuse_percentage")
public boolean balternate_jointuse_percentage;

@Column(name="ndiv_id")
public Integer ndiv_id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPQL queries against entities, it won’t affect the database directly. so use model name instead of table name

```
@Repository
    public interface DepartmentsRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Integer> 
    {
        @Query("select d from Department d")
        public List<Department> findColumns();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA doe not deal with table names, so if you want to write your query in JPA Query Language(JPQL) use fully-classified (package_name.class_name) entity names instead of table names.

So your query will look like this

```
@Query(value = "select d from package_name.Department d")
public List<Department> findColumns();
```

Or you can also run plain sql query in the `@Query` annotation using `nativeQuery=true`, So your code will look like

```
@Query(value = "select d from department d", nativeQuery=true)
public List<Department> findColumns();
```